# Issues with setting "Make Reader the default PDF viewer" with Adobe Reader XI

Tags: deployment, adobe, adobe-reader

I do a silent deployment of Adobe Reader XI and the setup doesn't set Adobe Reader as default PDF Reader.

I can set the default Reader manually but it has to be done automatically.

I tried:

```
msiexec /i  "AcroRead.msi" /q TRANSFORMS="TransformFile.mst" 
msiexec /i  "AcroRead.msi" /q TRANSFORMS="TransformFile.mst" IW_DEFAULT_VERB=Read
msiexec /i  "AcroRead.msi" /q IW_DEFAULT_VERB=Read
```

Adobe Reader installs fine but it doesn't set itself as default Reader. I have to open the Reader manually and set it in settings again. But this is impractical.

The same problem is described by another user [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1446399).
Does someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find the cause but I found a solution. Adobe Reader launches AdobeARM.exe to set itself as default Reader. So I have to use this command to force Adobe Reader as default PDF viewer after Reader installation:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe"  /FixPDF {AC76BA86-7AD7-1031-7B44-AB0000000001}
```

The GUID is Adobe Readers MSI ProductCode.